# Advice: MySQL Database, using concatened data as single row or create several rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a table (with MySQL) to store some data, but i'm not sure of the way to do it properly, because of the amount of data. For example if it's adress book database. 
so there is a table for users and  a table for contacts. Each users can own hundreds of contacts, and there could be thousans of users. Should I add a new row for every single contact (it will make a lot of rows!), or can i just concatenate all of them in one row with the user id.

uuh, this is just an example, but in my case once contacts are `INSERTED` they will never be `UPDATED` so, no modifications, they can only be `DELETED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go by the normal forms, you should have three tables

```
 1) Users -> {User_id} (primary key)
 2) Contacts -> {Contact_id} (primary key)
 3) Users_Contacts -> {User_id, Contact_id} (Compound key)
```

The `Junction` table `Users_Contacts` will have one record per contact - meaning for each unique value of User_id+Contact_id, there will be one record.

However, In practice, it is not always necessary to stick to the rule book. Depending on the use case, it is often advisable to have a denormalized table. The call is yours.

There is also another option of using NoSQL with MySQL. For example, the contacts can be serialized into JSON and stored. Mysql 5.7 seem to support this data format (with some external help). [See this for details.](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/)

Comment: I disagree with the third table for this problem. The "Junction" or "Link" table practice is generally used for many-to-many relationships, where this is a many-to-one setup, and it would only add complexity. Simply adding the user ID to the contact row would suffice.

Comment: The same contact could be linked to more than one user. I saw it as many-to-many. Thats an assumption I made, I could be wrong

Comment: I was trying to point out that the "Link" table method is not the default approach, and is really only used when necessary, as it creates more work for the programmer and the DBA.

Comment: I don't disagree, But **theory book** normalization requires this.

Comment: Then I would go so far as to say that **theory book** normalization is wrong and should be revamped.

Comment: In deed it's not a 'many-to-many' relationship but a many-to-one' relationship. But the JSON approach seems interesting, i'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Say for eg: If you add 3 contacts for a single user and as you mentioned you would be deleting contacts the its better to insert all three contacts, each in a new row with its user id. Because if you want to delete any one of the contact from 3 of them, then it will be easy.

Comment: Like i said i will not modify the data. If there is a need to be deleted, all of them will be deleted. Removing just one or two of contacts (for single row containing concatented data) is considered as an UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate all the contacts for an user and add them in one row could land up many issues. What in future the requirement changes and you need to make a layout all the contacts for an user with edit/delete individual contacts. So you should have one contact in each row.

You can optimize your query by indexing the columns.

Say userid#1234 has 1000 contacts in contact table where the primary key in contact table is idcontact (Indexed by default) and then in contact table another field called "iduser" which is also indexed, then the select performance over an iduser on contact table will be fast.

Ideally its the best approach using mysql database. There are examples of many apps where it maintains millions of data so it should be fine with a contact table and for each contact a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about lots of rows. You have to keep in-mind the granularity of control the user would expect (deleting / adding a contact, rearranging the list based on different factors, etc). It's always better to break things out into their owns rows if they are going to be treated independently from a similar item (contacts, users, addresses, etc). Additionally, if you were to concatenate your data, re-ordering for display or removing data becomes extremely resource intensive. Where as MySQL is designed to do exactly that "on the cheap".

MySQL can easily handle millions of rows of data. If you are worried about speed, just make sure your indexes are in-place before your data collection is too big (I would venture a guess, and say you'll need to index the user ID the contact belongs to and the first/last names). Indexes are a double-edged sword, however, as they take up disk space, but allow fast querying of large data sets. So you don't want to go over-board and index everything, only what you'll be sorting/searching by.

(Why on earth will contacts never be updated?...)

Comment: ok, this is reassuring, but in my case it's not really an active address book, (wich will be updated, sorted...) but a set of contacts for another process. And, once the contacts have been inserted, they will not be modified, the operations will be insertion and deletion, no update, no sorting

Comment: Even with that being the case, I still recommend what I said. Concatenation just invites a big host of issues to deal with.